# How to make a checkbox appear checked in thymeleaf?

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to get a checkbox checked if the object I send in the model has a particular attribute set to true (in this case mentor).

```
<label th:text="Mentor">Mentor </label>:<span th:text="${useraux.mentor}"/>
        <input type="checkbox" th:checked="${useraux.mentor}" th:field="${useraux.mentor}" ng-model="mentor"></input>
```

I know it is true, because it gives me this output.
[image]
But it does not activate the checkbox, I have tried many ways and I am not able to get it checked.

Comment: I see `ng-model` on there, is that angular? you just need to add the `checked` attribute to the input.

Comment: There I use angular so that if it is checked, extra fields appear.  Even if I add checked to the input it does not change anything.

Comment: If you have the attribute on there like `<input type="checkbox" checked>` or `checked="true"` it should display as checked. If not, there's something else interfering like CSS or an attribute change or something somewhere, would need a reproducible example to troubleshoot it though.

Comment: Remove the ngModel=.... thing which seems like angular, which works on client side modification. Remove it temporarily, check it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to set a condition on checked, if it comes as true you want the checkbox to be checked. Just set a condition on the property checked in your input, like this:

TS:

```
export class AppComponent {
  isChecked = 'thisTrue';
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="isChecked == 'thisTrue'" /> //this will be checked
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="isChecked == 'no'" /> //this wont be checked
```